Nginx can't find .js files?
I am attempting to host my Flutter web app on my home server running Nginx. My index.html loads fine when going to the ip, but included .js files aren't loaded. The request returns 502: GET http://192.168.1.187/test.js
index.html, using test.js as an example.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="plant_monitor">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
<!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>plant_monitor</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = "1760324881";
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
<!--  <script src="./flutter.js" defer></script> -->
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    console.log(window.location);
  </script>
</body>
</html>

By default, flutter set base href to "/", but I also tried it with "./" and now without.
nginx default.conf:
# "You are not configured" page, which is the default if another default doesn't exist
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        set $forward_scheme "http";
        set $server "127.0.0.1";
        set $port "80";

        server_name localhost-nginx-proxy-manager;
        access_log /data/logs/fallback_access.log standard;
        error_log /data/logs/fallback_error.log warn;
        include conf.d/include/assets.conf;
        include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;
        include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;

#       index index.html;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        location ~* \.(js|jpg|png|css)$ {}
#       location ~* \.(?:css|js|map|jpe?g|gif|png)$ { }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}

# First 443 Host, which is the default if another default doesn't exist
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        set $forward_scheme "https";
        set $server "127.0.0.1";
        set $port "443";

        server_name localhost;
        access_log /data/logs/fallback_access.log standard;
        error_log /dev/null crit;
        include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
        ssl_reject_handshake on;

        return 444;
}

The folder usr/share/nginx/html contains index.html, test.js, along with the actual flutter generated files I need when I can figure out how to load test.js.

Remove the empty location block defined for the js files.

I tried without that at first, with the same result. @J.Titus

Status code 502 is a "gateway error". What exactly does this IP address point to? Also, look at the access and error logs to check if this Nginx instance is responding with the status code.

The IP points to my raspberry pi. After checking the logs I see this error: *7002 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, localhost-nginx-proxy-manager, request: "GET /test.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:80/test.js", host: "192.168.1.187", referrer: "http://192.168.1.187/" >
